# Copying single cell value from different closed workbooks in a sharepoint

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have one master workbook and 20 other workbooks in a SharePoint.  Currently I am using the following code to retrive a single cell value from the closed workbook which is working very fine.

```
Sub Example()

Dim wbPath As String, wbName As String
Dim wsName As String, cellRef As String
Dim Ret As String

wbPath = "http://*****/2014/"

wbName = "overview 2014.xlsm"
wsName = "Sheet1"
cellRef = "E2"

Ret = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & _
      wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, -4150)

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Ret)

End Sub
```

Now I actually wanted to get the same cell value which needs to be copied from all workbooks from the SharePoint into the Master workbook ranges A5, A6, A7, A8.... etc.

Can some one please help me or give me a hint on how to copy same cell values from different closed workbooks from the same sharepoint location?

I have actually tried with the following code for other workbooks and working fine, but just wanted to know is there any other smarter way to reduce number of lines in the code?

```
 wbPath = "http://*****/2014/"

 wbName = "overview 2014.xlsm"
 wsName = "Sheet1"
 cellRef = "E2"

 Ret = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & _
      wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, xlR1C1)

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A4").Value = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Ret)

wbName = "workbook2.xlsm"
wsName = "sheet1"
cellRef = "E2"

Ret = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & _
      wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, -4150)

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A5").Value = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Ret)

wbName = "workbook3.xlsm"
wsName = "sheet1"
cellRef = "E2"

Ret = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & _
      wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, -4150)

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A6").Value = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Ret)

wbName = "workbook4.xlsm"
wsName = "sheet1"
cellRef = "E2"

Ret = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & _
      wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, -4150)

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A7").Value = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Ret)

wbName = "workbook5.xlsm"
wsName = "sheet1"
cellRef = "E2"

Ret = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & _
      wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, -4150)

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A8").Value = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Ret)

wbName = "workbook6.xlsm"
wsName = "sheet1"
cellRef = "E2"

Ret = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & _
      wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, -4150)

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A9").Value = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Ret)

wbName = "Workbook7.xlsm"
wsName = "sheet1"
cellRef = "E2"

Ret = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & _
      wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, -4150)

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A10").Value = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Ret)

wbName = "workbook8.xlsm"
wsName = "sheet1"
cellRef = "E2"

Ret = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & _
      wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, -4150)

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A11").Value = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Ret)

wbName = "workbook9.xlsm"
wsName = "sheet1"
cellRef = "E2"

Ret = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & _
      wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, -4150)

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A13").Value = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Ret)

wbName = "workbook10.xlsm"
wsName = "sheet1"
cellRef = "E2"

Ret = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & _
      wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, -4150)

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A14").Value = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Ret)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce the code I would use additional function:

```
Function getValue(wbPath As String, wbName As String, wsName As String, cellRef As String)
    Dim Ret As String
    Ret = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & _
            wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, -4150)
    getValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Ret)
End Function
```

and then call it like this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer, wbs

    wbs = Array("overview 2014.xlsm", "workbook2.xlsm", _
                "workbook3.xlsm", "workbook4.xlsm", _
                "workbook5.xlsm", "workbook6.xlsm", _
                "workbook7.xlsm", "workbook8.xlsm", _
                "workbook9.xlsm", "workbook10.xlsm")
    ' LBound(wbs) = 0
    For i = LBound(wbs) To UBound(wbs)
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A4").Offset(i).Value = _
            getValue("http://*****/2014/", CStr(wbs(i)), "sheet1", "E2")
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Everything is working fine, but the current challenge is cell `A4` value is not getting updated, I think it is because of `(CellRef).Address`.  Is there a way to update the values in cell `A4`?  I actually tried chaning the code to `Range(cellRef).Value` but I am getting an error message.  Please help me.

Comment: I don't have sharepoint or remote drive to test it, but with workbooks on my machine it works well (aslo I found little error in code, should be `getValue("http://*****/2014/", CStr(wbs(i)), "sheet1", "E2")` instead `getValue("http://*****/2014/", wbs(i), "sheet1", "E2")`)..Try to change `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`

Comment: Sure.  I am on vacation, hence I will text it once I come and let you know.  Once again thank you so much for your help